# how to move uploaded multiple images at once in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload 3 images fields, store them in my database and move the uploaded file in a folder.

For now, the "image1", 'image2", "image3", "image4" fields are inserting into MySQL database, but only "image1" is uploading and moving into my folder.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $pro_image1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
  $pro_image2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
  $pro_image3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
  $pro_image4 = $_FILES['image4']['name'];
  $tmp_name   = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
  $tmp2_name  = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
  $tmp3_name  = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
  $tmp4_name  = $_FILES['image4']['tmp_name'];

  $pro_query = "INSERT INTO product(image1,image2,image3,image4) VALUES('$pro_image1','$pro_image2','$pro_image3','$pro_image4')";

  if(mysqli_query($con,$pro_query)){
    $msg = "<p class='pull-right' style='color:green;'> Product Added successfully</p>";
    $path = "images/$pro_image1";

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path)) {
      copy($path, "../$path");
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp2_name, $path)) {
      copy($path, "../$path");
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp3_name, $path)) {
      copy($path, "../$path");
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp4_name, $path)) {
      copy($path, "../$path");
    } elseif(!mysqli_query($con,$pro_query)) {
      $insert_error = "<p class='pull-right' style='color:red;>Product didn't added</p>";
    }
  }
}

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="form-font">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Image1</label>
      <input type="file" name="image1" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Image2</label>
      <input type="file" name="image2" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Image3</label>
      <input type="file" name="image3" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Image4</label>
      <input type="file" name="image4" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <center>
      <input type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Add Product'>
    </center>
  </div>
</form>
```

How to move the other images ("image2", "image3", "image4") in my folder?
What is the mistake I made in my code? Could you please explain me where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path)){
             copy($path, "images/$pro_image2");
           }
           if(move_uploaded_file($tmp2_name, $path)){
             copy($path, "images/$pro_image3");
           }if(move_uploaded_file($tmp3_name, $path)){
             copy($path, "images/$pro_image4");
           }if(move_uploaded_file($tmp4_name, $path)){
             //copy($path, "images/$path");
           }
```

Comment: It would be good if you could add some explanations to your code, to understand how you solve the problem

Comment: if you take a look at the original code you will notice the difference between my code and his code, it doesn't need that big of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

please overrite your $path variable then it will upload property..

before if condition change $path varibale like below or change the variable to $path1,$path2,$path3..

```
$path = "images/$pro_image1";
$path = "images/$pro_image2";
$path = "images/$pro_image3";
```

-

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $pro_image1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
        $pro_image2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
        $pro_image3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
        $pro_image4 = $_FILES['image4']['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
        $tmp2_name = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
        $tmp3_name = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
        $tmp4_name = $_FILES['image4']['tmp_name'];
$pro_query = "INSERT INTO product(image1,image2,image3,image4) VALUES('$pro_image1','$pro_image2','$pro_image3','$pro_image4')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$pro_query)){
            $msg = "<p class='pull-right' style='color:green;'> Product Added successfully</p>";
            $path = "images/$pro_image1";
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path)){
                 copy($path, "../$path");
               }
               $path = "images/$pro_image2";
               if(move_uploaded_file($tmp2_name, $path)){
                 copy($path, "../$path");
               }
               $path = "images/$pro_image3";
               if(move_uploaded_file($tmp3_name, $path)){
                 copy($path, "../$path");
               }
               $path = "images/$pro_image4";
               if(move_uploaded_file($tmp4_name, $path)){
                 copy($path, "../$path");
               }
               elseif(!mysqli_query($con,$pro_query)){
            $insert_error = "<p class='pull-right' style='color:red;>Product didn't added</p>";
        }
    }
}

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="form-font">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
                <label>Image1</label>
                <input type="file" name="image1" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Image2</label>
                <input type="file" name="image2" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Image3</label>
                <input type="file" name="image3" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Image4</label>
                <input type="file" name="image4" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
<center><input type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Add Product'></center>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have var $path defined only for image1 -- you need to change this var within each "if" block for functions  move_uploaded_file and copy.
At the moment you use just path and filename for image1 for all images.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to named them like "image[0], image[1], image[2]"
Changes in your code

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="form-font">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label>Image1</label>
           <input type="file" name="image[0]" class="form-control" required>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label>Image2</label>
           <input type="file" name="image[1]" class="form-control" required>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Image3</label>
            <input type="file" name="image[2]" class="form-control" required>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Image4</label>
            <input type="file" name="image[3]" class="form-control" required>
       </div>
       <center><input type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Add Product'></center>
   </form>
```